# How to control trimming of strace messages?

Tags: strace

`strace` likes to trim messages, for example:

```
sendto(4, "\4\356\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\4[more content]"..., 44, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 44
```

Can I tell `strace` to print N bytes (or even *all* bytes) rather than trimming at some predefined point? The `man` page is the size of a small novel, and searching for "trim", "shorten" etc. yielded nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Searching for "bytes" did it: **`-s strsize` controls the number of bytes printed.** Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any way to print *everything* - `-s 0` prints an empty string, and `-s -1` is considered an invalid argument.

Comment: Strace [limits](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/strace.c#L1669) the string size limit to -1U/4, which on most systems is a little over 1 billion.